# 502 Bad Gateway Django nginx-gunicorn-postgres

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Доброго времени. Знаю, что таких вопросов много в интернете, но я там не нашел ответа. Поэтому выдаёт ошибка 502 Bad Gateway. Пытаюсь запустить на VPS сервере.

**/etc/init/gunicorn.conf**

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling yim"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid root
setgid www-data
chdir /root/yim

exec env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/yim/yim.sock yim.wsgi:application
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/yim**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 178.124.139.108;

    location /static/ {
         root /root/yim;
    }
    location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/root/yim/yim.sock;
    }
}
```

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', '178.124.139.108']
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Comment: Ну так у вас пути к unix-сокету прописаны разные

Comment: Извините, я вставил другую версию. Изменил как есть сейчас

Comment: @ArtemNester что в  логах nginx'a и gunicorn'a ?

Comment: @ArtemNester круто. Но что в логах ? Ошибки и т.д.

Comment: @matz

 2017/09/03 13:23:40 [crit] 1092#0: *7 connect() to unix:/root/willpy/willpy.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.60.2.171, server: 178.124.139.108, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/root/willpy/willpy.sock:/", host: "178.124.139.108"

Comment: @ArtemNester Логи веб сервера добавьте к вопросу и отформатируйте.
Ошибка с правами доступа - `Permission denied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что файлы проекта находились внутри каталога /root/, которая видимо напичкана правами безопасности. Соответственно из-за этого права доступа к сокету тоже были ограничены. Поэтому файлы проекта лучше всего выносить за этот каталог.

Comment: Лучше не запускать ничего лишнего от имени root